# emacs 24.2 tab-width always set to 2

Tags: emacs24

I've been trying to get to work my `tab-width` variable, but apparently I can't with my configuration. It supposed to be working with the first two lines but nothing. And the problem is that I always get 2 spaces for indentation and never 4. I copy the important part of the code.

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)

(mapc (lambda (hook)
        (add-hook hook (lambda ()
                         (setq-default tab-width 4))))
      '(js2-mode-hook
        js-mode-hook
        css-mode-hook
        less-css-mode-hook
        php-mode-hook
        html-mode-hook
))
```

I've been trying to modify a little bit the configuration, but there is not a lot to do about it.

Comment: You first have to realize that "tab-width set to N" and "N spaces for indentation" are two unrelated concepts.

Comment: Before my python mode always get tab width wrong. Later i figure out there's guess tab width in it which cause the problem. Maybe you should also check if you have that kind of things in the modes. Good luck

Comment: I didn't remember I had this question. Thanks to @enchanter that just commented and remind me about it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to answer to my own question when I solved my problem (it was a while ago). The next is the part of my code in my emacs initialization file. I had to configure manually some emacs-modes, but it's working.

```
;; indentiation stuff (maybe some variable is missing for other language
(setq-default indent-line-function 4)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4)
(setq-default lisp-indent-offset 4)
(setq-default sgml-basic-offset 4)
(setq-default nxml-child-indent 4)
(setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 4 200 4))
```

I hope it solves somebody's problem too.